# How to invalidateQueries with JWT Tokens in the Context?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context, react-query

I am using short-lived JWT tokens to access my API; Token needs to be fetched every 10 mins or so. My root `App` component fetches the token on a interval, sets it into local state and passed to context where all my components can access it.

```
function App() {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient()

    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
        isValid: null,
        token: null,
        user: null
    })

    //Get User and API Token
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchToken = async () => {
            try {
                const fetchItem = await fetch(
                    'http://someLocalHost:5000/user',
                    {
                        credentials: 'include'
                    }
                )
                const fetchResponse = await fetchItem.json();
                console.log(fetchResponse)
                if (fetchItem.status === 200) {
                    setAuth({
                        isValid: true,
                        token: fetchResponse['token'],
                        user: fetchResponse['user']
                    });
                }
            } catch {
                setAuth({isValid: false});
            }
        };
        var intervalCall;
        if (auth.isValid === true) {
            intervalCall = setInterval(fetchToken, 200000);
        } else if (auth.isValid === false) {
            return
        } else {
            fetchToken();
        }

        return () => {
            clearInterval(intervalCall);
        };
    }, [auth.isValid]);

    const authContext = {
        user: auth.user,
        token: auth.token,
        login: (props) => {
            setAuth({
                isValid: true,
                token: props.token,
                user: props.user,
            })
        },
        logout: () => {
            setAuth({
                isValid: false
            })
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
                    <Router>
                        <Nav />
                        <main>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
                            </Switch>
                        </main>
                    </Router>
                </AuthContext.Provider>
            </QueryClientProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App
```

I use react-query to fetch, store and update API data. My components typically look something like this:

```
function Index() {
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

    );
    const usersQuery = useQuery(
        'users',
        () => fetchData({url: '/users', token: auth.token})
    );


    return (
        <div>
            <UserList list={usersQuery.data} />
            <NewUser />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Index
```

I really like the ability to `invalidateQueries` to cause a re-fetch of data. `New User` component uses mutation and then invalidates 'users' query.

```
function NewUser() {
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    const newUserMutation = useMutation(formData => fetchPUT({
        url: 'new_user',
        type: 'PUT',
        token: auth.token,
        formData: formData
    }), {
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries('users');
        }
    });

    const addUser = (user_id) => {
        var fetchData = new FormData();
        fetchData.append('user_id', user_id);

        newUserMutation.mutate(fetchData);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => addUser('someUserID')}>Create New User</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NewUser
```

This works great until 200000ms passes, my root component fetches a new authentication token and updates the context. Once the context updates `invalidateQueries` doesn't trigger and `refetchOnWindowFocus` doesn't trigger. Only a refresh fixes it. I am assuming it's caused by the way react-query hashes query keys so I tried to add the authentication token and url into the query keys array then use `queryKeys` inside my fetch function.

```
const usersQuery = useQuery(
    ['users', {url: '/users', token: auth.token}],
    fetchData
);
```

But to no avail. Does anyone have an idea what causes this? Is it my structure? Remounting the `Index` component every time context changes worked but with many nested components this will become a pain.

*This is a simplified structure of my component tree only showing relevant code, actual structure is much more nested and complex.*

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It's all about the structure.
If anyone else runs into this. Here is the solution:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient()
```

This created a new instance of `QueryClient` every time state of the `App` component changes. The new client doesn't have any of the old mounted queries attached to it.
Ended up moving all the authentication to a child component and leaving `QueryClient` and `QueryClientProvider` in the root `App` element which never re-renders or re-mounts